# App Engine multiple "Committed before 500 null" errors image

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine

Hi I am working on a photo web application and keep getting the following errors whenever I generate requests too fast, for example - clicking on a photo album multiple times resulting in the server side having to serve too many photos in a short time. Suspect that it is just my local machine not having enough memory. Will I encounter the same problem if it is in the cloud?

```
Aug 8, 2012 5:30:47 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error for /_ah/img/eQaAh6XKGrl39oZ5BZgVcQ=s500
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Aug 8, 2012 5:30:47 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error for /_ah/img/RHDL5oC2G-hrgw2rVCj4wQ=s500
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Aug 8, 2012 5:30:47 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Committed before 500 null
Aug 8, 2012 5:30:47 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /_ah/img/a09PBMb4WLfIZYKCyGA7fQ=s500
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1024)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.sendError(Response.java:240)....
```

Comment: Why don't you try it in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really possible to give you a definitive answer based on the details in your question.

To avoid this type of error locally, you can increase the heap size by adding `--jvm_flag=-Xmx1024m` (or some other value instead of 1024) when invoking `dev_appserver.sh`. Increase the value if you keep encountering the error.

If you deploy and you still see the issue, you may need to [change your frontend class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#Setting_the_Frontend_Instance_Class) to one with more memory. Higher instance classes come with more memory (and CPU) but cost more per instance-hour.